# How to get two datetime fields difference in days and hours in postgresql view?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have the data in table like below:

```
  **start_date**                         **end_date**
---------------                      -----------------
2011-06-27 13:24:45.137417          2011-06-28 05:34:26.54939
2011-09-30 09:09:00.501381          2011-10-03 23:38:46.479824
```

the expected result would be like below:

```
Diff
-------
0.16
3.14
```

where the digits before the decimal point is "Days" & after decimal point is "Hours"

i try it using 
extract('epoch' from (end_date-start_date))/(3600*24)

but it gives the "hours" value in format of 100 i.e 0.673395971909722 for the first record & 3.60400438012731 for second record

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See formatting functions in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html).

```
SELECT to_char(end_date - start_date, 'D.HH24') AS diff FROM your_table;
```

```
0.16
3.14
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 But just a note, in my case only works if the format is 'DD.HH24'