# PostgreSQL: Date Difference with fractions

Tags: postgresql, date

```
SELECT cu.user_id, cu.last_activity, cu.updated_time, 
       DATE_PART('day', cu.last_activity - cu.updated_time), to_char(end_date - start_date, 'DD.HH24') 
FROM stats.core_users cu 
WHERE cu.user_id = '117132014' or cu.user_id = '117132012';
```

Get the result like:

```
117132014   2017-12-11 10:34:51.349905  2017-12-09 12:00:38.503518  1 01.22
117132012   2017-12-11 05:18:20.312283  2017-12-08 15:46:51.914085  2 02.13
```

Is is feasible to get the day difference with fractions like 1.91 days in the first case, instead of 1 days and 22 hours, to be more precise and easier to fit in a machine learning model?

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110055/how-to-get-two-datetime-fields-difference-in-days-and-hours-in-postgresql-view

Answer (score 0):

`date_part()` does what it's name says: it returns one part of several elements from a date, interval or timestamp. In your case it's one part of an interval (because `timestamp - timestamp` returns an `interval`).

If you want the result as a fraction, you need to `extract` the seconds of the interval and then divide that by 86400 (which is the number of seconds in a day)

```
extract(epoch from cu.last_activity - cu.updated_time) / 86400
```